# What header do I need in order to use UNIX library punction clear()

Tags: c, unix, curses

all I was compiling a source of my UNIX today when I noticed the following

```
warning: implicit declaration of function 'clear'
```

After I made a debug with the GDB on the binary, these came out:

```
0x090000002a242594 in clear () from /usr/lib/libcurses.a(shr42_64.o)
0x090000002a242600 in wclear () from /usr/lib/libcurses.a(shr42_64.o)
0x090000002a238a80 in werase () from /usr/lib/libcurses.a(shr42_64.o)
0x090000002a238b00 in wmove () from /usr/lib/libcurses.a(shr42_64.o)
0x090000002a238a9c in werase () from /usr/lib/libcurses.a(shr42_64.o)
0x090000002a238600 in wclrtobot () from /usr/lib/libcurses.a(shr42_64.o)
0x090000002a237f80 in wclrtoeol () from /usr/lib/libcurses.a(shr42_64.o)
```

It seems that it's some kind of a UNIX library "libcurses.a"

How should I include this library in my file in order to get rid of that warning ?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <curses.h> // See it's here, stop the silly questions
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
```

Thanks !

Comment: Yes, it does. It's the very first top of the file row 18. The clear() call is at row 67.

Comment: move(y,x) is a macros, just like clear() but it is not generating a warning.

_CURSES_USE_MACROS may be defined ....

Comment: Was this compiler-message the first one? If not, please quote the first one. (Also, don't forget to add these options to gcc:  `-W -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Werror`)

Comment: I am compiling with: 

{ gcc -pthread -fPIC -DAIX -maix64 -DSYSTEME_64 -Wall -fexceptions -c src.c -o src.o }

As I see, there is no "-libcurses". May be that's it. What do you guys think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the stacktrace showing `shr42_64.o`, your system seems to be some version of AIX, e.g., 5.x for example.  Running

```
ar tv /usr/lib/libcurses.a
```

would show something like

```
r--r--r--     2/2     493219 Aug 05 05:38 2011 shr42.o
r--r--r--     2/2     377211 Aug 05 05:38 2011 shr4.o
r--r--r--     2/2     194484 Aug 05 05:38 2011 shr.o
```

The corresponding header `/usr/include/curses.h` has the prototype for `clear()` ifdef'd within

```
#if     defined(NOMACROS) || defined(lint)

#if defined(__STDC__) || !defined(_NO_PROTO)
```

and (assuming your compiler really uses *that* header) the latter line is what is *used*.  From the comment about `gdb`, it seems likely that you also are using `gcc`.  Usually `gcc` will define `__STDC__` (though some [very old](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Non-bugs.html) port may not).  If there is no problem with that definition, it is possible that something defined `_NO_PROTO`.  Alternatively, your system could have some conflicting header file.  To resolve *what* is the case, I would generate the preprocessor-output file (using options `-E`, `-P` and `-C` as [documented](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Invocation.html#Invocation)) and look to see which "curses.h" file was included, and which ifdef was actually used.

Comment: That's correct. It is an AIX Unix machine Thanks for the comment, I will be sure to try this out !

Comment: It's actually "Welcome to AIX Version 7.1!" ;) Compiling with

 { gcc -pthread -fPIC -DAIX -maix64 -DSYSTEME_64 -Wall -fexceptions -c src.c -o src.o }

Comment: It says {  src.pc:17:0: warning: "__STDC__" redefined  } After I defined it

Comment: I wouldn't (re)define `__STDC__`, but look in the generated ".i" file for the pathname of the "curses.h" (to check that it's from /usr/include) and look for the first mention of "clear".

Answer (score 0):

This error is not about including the library as much as including the function declaration, which means you need to `#include <curses.h>`. (see [man](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_clear.3x.html) page)

Comment: If I already had it in my source and it did the job ( which I have ). Do you think that I will make a bother to write here fol help ?

Comment: I can't assume what you don't mention (as anyone else). so I don't know what you would bother or not.